# How to simplify the following expression using boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, simplify, simplification, boolean-algebra

How to simplify the following expression using boolean algebra?

`a[b'c+ (b+c')'](a'b+c)`

Answer (score 0):

We have `A[B'C + (B+C')'](A'B + C)=` 
for Moore's Law we have `(B+C')'=B'C` :
`=A[B'C + B'C](A'B + C) = [AB'C + AB'C](A'B + C) =`
Multiplying :
`= [AB'C + AB'C](A'B + C) =`
`X+X=X` then `AB'C + AB'C = AB'C`:
`= AB'C (A'B + C) =`
Multiplying :
`=AB'CA'B + AB'CC=` 
we have that `X*X'=0` so `AB' * A'B * C = 0 * C= 0` and we have that `X*X=X` so `AB'C*C= AB'C`
The final result is :
`= AB'C`